# Update a list property of a node by values of a CSV file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to update the list property of one node in my DB by a CSV file. The node's name is `Class` and it has two properties `name` of type string and `vector` of type list of string. The CSV file has two columns `nameCSV` and `vectorCSV` and some rows have the same value for the `nameCSV` column but different values for the `vectorCSV` column. So I want to update the `vector` property by adding the values of the `vectorCSV` when their corresponding names are equal. I wrote this query in Cypher but it doesn't work:

```
load  CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test2.csv" AS  vector
MATCH (c:Class) 
Merge( nv:CSVfile {nameCSV: vector.nameCSV,vectorCSV:vector.vectorCSV})
where c.name = nv.nameCSV
set c.vector = c.vector + nv.vectorCSV
```

How should I change this query to update the list property `vector` of the node `Class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the `vector` property on the `Class` nodes is already an array.

```
LOAD  CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test2.csv" AS  vector
MATCH (c:Class {name: vector.nameCSV})
SET c.vector=c.vector + vector.vectorCSV
```

This could result in duplicate values. If you do not want duplicates, you can use [apoc.coll.union](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.union/)

```
LOAD  CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test2.csv" AS  vector
MATCH (c:Class {name: vector.nameCSV})
SET c.vector=apoc.coll.union(c.vector,[vector.vectorCSV])
```

Comment: This works. I had solved with but I couldn't remove the duplicates!